# Infix calculator with standard order of operations

Tags: calc

I've been using `quick-calc` for years because it seems like the most sane calculator and it can do a lot of things. But is there really no calculator for Emacs that supports infix notation and uses the regular order of operations? I'm looking for a way to do calculations within Emacs where `50/10*100` evaluates to `500` [as it should](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=50%2F10*100&dataset=). Emacs calculators using a non-standard order of operations has screwed up too many of my calculations recently.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. But interestingly, that variable also affects the behavior of `quick-calc`. So you can post it as an answer if you want (or I can accept it as a duplicate anyway).

Comment: Well, I considered reposting my answer from there, but that felt kind of silly. But I guess the focus of this question is a bit different, so I can quote a different manual page.

Comment: I don't think this is going to be a very helpful comment, but I have to point out that if you get used to the RPN mode then all of your operator precedence worries simply disappear.

Comment: And FWIW, personally I would *always* use parens if writing something like `50/10*100` in order to make it unambiguous.  I don't believe I've ever had an expectation of *everything* interpreting such sequences in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to do calculations within Emacs where `50/10*100` evaluates to `500`

Set `calc-multiplication-has-precedence` to `nil`, then `calc` (and `quick-calc`) will do that.

[(calc) Customizing Calc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Customizing-Calc.html)

> -- Variable: `calc-multiplication-has-precedence`
>
> The variable `calc-multiplication-has-precedence` determines
>    whether multiplication has precedence over division in algebraic
>    formulas in normal language modes.  If
>    `calc-multiplication-has-precedence` is non-`nil`, then
>    multiplication has precedence (and, for certain obscure reasons, is
>    right associative), and so for example `a/b*c` will be interpreted
>    as `a/(b*c)`. If `calc-multiplication-has-precedence` is `nil`,
>    then multiplication has the same precedence as division (and, like
>    division, is left associative), and so for example `a/b*c` will be
>    interpreted as `(a/b)*c`.  The default value of
>    `calc-multiplication-has-precedence` is `t`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is a little annoying. The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Algebraic-Tutorial.html) says “Notice: Calc gives ‘/’ lower precedence than ‘*’, so that ‘a/b*c’ is interpreted as ‘a/(b*c)’; this is not standard across all computer languages. See below for details.”

You might try [infix.el](https://github.com/rspeele/infix.el). Then you can use elisp e.g. M-: `($ 50/10*100)`. There's also M-x `calculator`.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW `M-x calculator` gives `500` for your formula.

Comment: But it doesn't support decimal places when all inputs are integers, so that's an extra thing to always keep in mind (and I'll always be scared of forgetting about that which is why I'll eventually go insane when using it, so I don't count it as a sane calculator, sorry).